# Playing SWF files locally from Android Webview

Tags: android, webview, flash

What is the right way to view .Swf files that plays .Flv videos in Android? The code that I am using right now to enable Flash support in web view is

```
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(mWebView.getSettings().LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

For the HTML file, I'm using swfObject.

The problem is that I can open up the SWF file just fine from third party apps like SWF Player from the market. In addition, I can load up the HTML page from the browser by calling it directly through file:///. However, when I load it up using my webview, I'm stuck with a blank screen. Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"...
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I had a similar problem on 3.2 and this solved it for me.  4.+ has this enabled by default (I believe).

D/.

Comment: mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);<--- this is not available in lollipop onwards API. So, what to do?