# playing .swf on application startup

Tags: android, flash, splash-screen

I want that i play .swf file when the android user clicks on the application icon and the application starts and after that i want to start the application's activity. Here is what i thought and what i have done until now. From http://web.archive.org/web/20130712051340/http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;

public class Splash_Screen extends Activity {
    
     private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.startup);
        
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             
            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */
 
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                String localUrl ="file:///android_asset/Kiss-o-meter.swf";

                WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
                wv.loadUrl(localUrl);       
                
                Intent yes_krao = new Intent(Splash_Screen.this, KissingMeter.class);
                startActivity(yes_krao);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
         
            
    }   
}
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
              android:orientation="vertical" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
     
     <WebView android:id="@+id/webview" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there anything wrong with it?? seems like the code is not working! secondly **setPluginsEnabled(true);** is also not being picked up by eclipse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startActivity(yes_krao)` is called immediately after you have loaded the `WebView` so the application will switch Activities before your .swf has a chance to play. One solution would be to implement a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and switch Activities after the duration of your .swf file.

E.g.:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;

public class Splash_Screen extends Activity {

     private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.startup);

        String localUrl ="file:///android_asset/Kiss-o-meter.swf";

        WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        wv.loadUrl(localUrl); 

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity      
                Intent yes_krao = new Intent(Splash_Screen.this, KissingMeter.class);
                startActivity(yes_krao);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }   
}
```

Note that **setPluginsEnabled()** has been deprecated, so you should use **setPluginState()**:

```
WebSettings webSettings = yourWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

Comment: Move the WebView code above the Handler (see my edited answer), so that code will be called first, and then after SPLASH_TIME_OUT the Intent is called and the Activity changes.

Comment: last thing sir. The file is in the assets folder?? am i accessing it the right way?? because i see a white screen for the time duration that has been set and then the main activity starts. The .swf file is not being played!

Comment: It may have something to do with this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280648/play-swf-files-from-internal-storage-in-android-webview-in-nexus-7-android OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381407/playing-swf-files-locally-from-android-webview?rq=1