# Embed SWF file to android splash screen

Tags: android

I have a swf file that has sound. I would like to embed the file to my App as a splash screen? What would be the best solution?

Like convert it to a video put there or any other solution?

Thanks!

Comment: @1owk3y: Wall paper feature. Not a duplicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997257/playing-swf-on-application-startup

Comment: @1owk3y: I already checked the link - he is using webview and I see most of the android devices don't support swf on webview.

Comment: You haven't really given us any context for this question... so as long as YOUR phone supports SWF on WebView, that answers your question. Obviously it would be unwise to distribute the app with SWF given the poor compatibility. The "best solution" is to stop leveraging Flash in your projects and use a more robust and supported multimedia platform.

Answer (score -1):

With swf file, you can:

- Using Webview to load file (be sure device support Flash)
- Or convert to video (ex: mp4,..) to embed in your activity (recommend)

Media supported: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

Comment: No idea. Anyways, I can't covert swf file to mp4.. The only option is mov file.